# How can I make input tag longer in grid system?

Tags: html, css, grid

I'm new to HTML and I am having a problem learning grid system in css.
The first image is what I have made with simple label and input tags.
However, I want to make the second input longer since it's where you type your email address. I tried including col-sm-12 but it doesn't seem to work.
The ideal look would be the second image. Any help?

```
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group">
    <label  for="form-phone" class="col">phone #</label>
    <div class="col">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-phone" name="phone" placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label  for="form-mail" class="col">E-mail</label>
    <div class="col sm-12">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-mail" name="mail" placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label  for="form-money" class="col">money</label>
    <div class="col">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-money" name="money" placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
</div>
```

[first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAGEE.png)

[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuLuH.png)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so `col-sm-12` is the part of a framework called [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/). What you want to do in the grid system, is when you want to spread them, you can always use `grid-template-columns` where you specify how many columns do you want, and put width, or you can put automatic width over `1fr` which takes 1 fraction of the screen. With your example, you can put 4 column, and you have 3 inputs, so you can put `colspan` on the email input I think, and that would make it larger than the other inputs. Anyways, on the bootstrap, which you mentioned with col-sm-12, 1 row has 12 spaces(call it that), if you want to put some larger than the other, you would go with 1 `div` being `col-sm-3`, the middle one would be `col-sm-6`, and the last one would be `col-sm-3`, which adds up to 12, if you understand. Feed free to ask in comments more.

```css
.grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr);
}
#spread{
  grid-column: 2 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<form action="" class="grid">
  <input type="text" name="" id="">
  <input type="text" name="" id="spread">
  <input type="text" name="" id="">
</form>
```

It looks something like this

Comment: @gwgaeh2 did you try this?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-3">
    <label for="form-phone" class="col">phone #</label>
    <div class="col">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-phone" name="phone" placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-4">
    <label for="form-mail" class="col">E-mail</label>
    <div class="col">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-mail" name="mail" placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-3">
    <label for="form-money" class="col">money</label>
    <div class="col">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-money" name="money" placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

just add `col-6` in `<div class="form-group col-6">`

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row ">
<div class="form-group">
    <label  for="form-phone" class="col">phone #</label>
    <div class="col">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-phone" name="phone" placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-6">
    <label  for="form-mail" class="col">E-mail</label>
    <div class="col">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-mail" name="mail" placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label  for="form-money" class="col">money</label>
    <div class="col">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-money" name="money" placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this, but the div with form-group col-6 moved to the right by a little so it didn't look good.

Comment: try to add col-3,col-5,col-3 in div with form-group

Comment: and also use latest bootstrap CDN